# ActiveRecord foreign key set to null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.8 and I have the following root resource:

```
class PointOfInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "Id"
  set_table_name  "POI"

  has_many :attributes, :foreign_key => 'POIId'
end
```

The point of interest can have several attributes:

```
class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "Id"
  set_table_name  "Attribute"

  belongs_to :point_of_interest, :foreign_key => 'POIId'

  has_one :multimedia, :foreign_key => 'Id', :primary_key => 'Value'
end
```

The attribute class may have media associated with it:

```
class Multimedia < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "Id"
  set_table_name  "Multimedia"
end
```

I am trying to insert a point of interest in my database like so:

```
poi = PointOfInterest.new
attr = poi.attributes.new
attr.SomeAttribute = 1
attr.build_multimedia(:content => 'test')
poi.save
```

This is properly persisting both the root (`PointOfInterest`) and the `Multimedia` record. The `Attribute`, however, is not being properly persisted. While the foreign key to the point of interest is properly set (`POIId`), the foreign key to the `Multimedia` record remains `null`.

Any clue as to why this is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship / foreign key are set at cross purposes.

If `Attribute` `has_one` `Multimedia`, then you need the `Multimedia` model to declare `belongs_to :attribute`, and the `Multimedia` table to contain a foreign key for `Attribute`.

I'm guessing that you can't change your database schema (otherwise, I'd have to ask why you're using non-Rails-standard table and key names); in which case you want to switch the sense of the relation. Make `Attribute belongs_to :multimedia`, and `Multimedia has_one :attribute`. Then the `Multimedia` FK in the `Attribute` table is pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I tried that, but it yields the same result. The `POIId` in the `Attribute` table is set correctly, but the ID of the Multimedia record (`Value` column in the `Attribute` table), is not.